# angular js file download issue due file name's space

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to download file using angular js. currently i am sending GET request to do it.

my file is = flower-red.jpg
my request like below
GET http://localhost:8080/aml/downloadDoc/852410507V/flower-red.jpg

this is correctly downloaded. but if file name have spaces, it did not downloaded. Please check this

file = flower - red.jpg
my request like below
GET http://localhost:8080/aml/downloadDoc/852410507V/flower%20-%20red.jpg

this is not download. because request is changed due to spaces in the file name .
how i fixed this issue.

Comment: This more likely has to do with your web server and how it is set up to interpret URLs. You could try using a `+` instead of `%20` to represent a space, but the real question is if the file with the space in the name exists on the server or not.

Answer (score -1):

```
// javascript 
var url = "http://localhost:8080/aml/downloadDoc/852410507V/flower - red.jpg";
var urlRemoveSpace = url.split(" ").join("");

// now you can process get request to download using variable urlRemoveSpace
```

Comment: Did you test this code? Because `url` does not have any space characters in it. It has `%20`, which is a space URL encoded, but that won't be found by JavaScript.

Comment: How removing spaces fixes the issue? The filename on the server-side still has spaces in it.